# Measuring Time Accurately in Swift for Comparison Across Devices

Tags: ios, swift, time

I need to be able to record reaction time, from when the screen loads or the question label refreshes until the user taps a number button. I'm not finding documentation from Apple on this to be very helpful. `NSDate` is not accurate enough, I need to measure to milliseconds at least. `mach_absolute_time` seems to be favored by game designers because it is internally consistent, but it won't work for this application because I need to compare data across devices, and `mach_absolute_time` is CPU dependent time. [This Apple Dev Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html) suggests using `NanosecondsToAbsolute` and `DurationToAbsolute` but it's in obj-c and I can't find a swift equivalent documentation.

Is there a swift version of `NanosecondsToAbsolute` and `DurationToAbsolute` that I'm just not finding? Some other way to do this consistently?

Here's the code I'm trying to add the times to:

```
class EmotionQuestionsViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//mark "startTime" when view loads
    }

    @IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!
    var timeResultsStack = [String]()

    var questionsStack = ["HAPPY", "ANXIOUS"]
    var questionResultsStack = [String]()
    var questionStackArrayIndex = 1

    @IBAction func RecordValueFromNumericalScaleOneToSeven(sender: UIButton) {

//mark durration time as currentTime - startTime, append to timeResultsStack

        let value = sender.currentTitle!
        questionResultsStack.append(value)

        if questionResultsStack.count < questionsStack.count{
            self.questionLabel.text = "how \(questionsStack[questionStackArrayIndex]) are you right now?"

//mark startTime when label is changed

            self.questionStackArrayIndex++

        }
        else{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showResults", sender: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "NSDate isn't accurate enough, I need at least milliseconds"? NSDate gives you sub microsecond precision. NSTimeInterval is _double_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSTimeInterval to measure time (much better than a timer). You just need to store two dates (two points in time) and subtract endTime - StartTime as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var startTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var endTime: TimeInterval = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }

    @IBAction func stopTimeAction(_ sender: Any) {
        endTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        print((endTime-startTime).time)
    }

}
```

---

```
extension TimeInterval {
    var time: String { .init(format: "%d:%02d:%02d.%03d", Int(self/3600),
                        Int((self/60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)),
                        Int(truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)),
                        Int((self*1000).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1000))) }
}
```

Comment: *"It is the ONLY way you can actually use to measure time"* – No.

Comment: Ok Martin R the only one I knew until today :) Thanks for the info once again

Answer (score 18):

As already said, the precision of `NSDate()` is probably good enough
for your purpose. Just for the sake of completeness, `mach_absolute_time()` from the referenced  [Technical Q&A QA1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html)
 
works in Swift as well:

```
let t1 = mach_absolute_time()
// do something
let t2 = mach_absolute_time()

let elapsed = t2 - t1
var timeBaseInfo = mach_timebase_info_data_t()
mach_timebase_info(&timeBaseInfo)
let elapsedNano = elapsed * UInt64(timeBaseInfo.numer) / UInt64(timeBaseInfo.denom);
print(elapsedNano)
```

Possible advantages of this method:

- Calling `mach_absolute_time()` seems to be *much faster* than calling
  `NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`, so this method might be
  better suited to measure extremely short intervals.
- The value of `NSDate()` changes if the clock is adjusted, 
  `mach_absolute_time()` does not have this problem.

Comment: Just curious; your claim that "_the precision of `NSDate()` is probably good enough for your purpose_" sounds to me there might be a even more precise method in retrieving time / date. May I ask: what would you personally use if precision is of interest regarding retrieval of time / date? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig: I said "probably" because I don't know if there is a difference in the accuracy of both methods. I added this answer only because OP explicitly asked for mach_absolute_time. – But I have added some information about the possible advantages.

Answer (score 3):

NSDate is tied to the realtime clock on iOS and Mac devices, and has sub-millisecond accuracy.

Use NSDate's timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate method to convert an NSDate (or the current time) to a double that is the number of seconds since January 1, 2001, including fractional seconds. Once you do that you're free to do math on the doubles that you get back.