# How to implement the mach_absolute_time Swift api?

Tags: ios, swift, time, timer

This may be a bit of a silly question, but I'm looking for a reliable way to create a repeating timer in Swift that's as completely accurate as possible. I've researched this quite a bit and have found that the mach_absolute_time api seems to be what I'm looking for.

However, while I think I understand mach_absolute_time, there's not much out there on mach_wait_until (if I understand correctly that's the mach api version of using `Timer.scheduledTimer()` to call a selector).

So my goal is to turn something like Martin R's answer to this post: [Measuring Time Accurately in Swift for Comparison Across Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583263/measuring-time-accurately-in-swift-for-comparison-across-devices) into a timer that can measure out an exact amount of time, call a selector, and repeat with little to no loss of time between ticks.

Thanks!

**Update**

The other thing I ran into is that the timer can't lock up the app while the it's running either – I know since mach is pretty low level, calling mach_wait_until will stop everything else and wait for the time to elapse (I think).

Comment: Did you read [TN2169
High Precision Timers in iOS / OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html)? It contains (among other advice) sample code using mach_wait_until.

Comment: I did - see update to question :)